# Why does CSS margin left and right increase size of element?

Tags: html, css

I have the following code :

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.blue {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: blue;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.violet {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.div {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  margin: 50px auto;
  display: flex;
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
}

.xont {
  width: 60%;
  margin: auto;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="xont">
  <div class="div">
    <div class="violet">This is div 1</div>
    <div class="blue">This is div 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

why the width of the `.div` element increase by 30px When I set the negative margin to -15px for left and right ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the part of the specification that describe how width of block element are calculated: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#blockwidth.

The formula is:

> The following constraints must hold among the used values of the other properties:
>
> `'margin-left' + 'border-left-width' + 'padding-left' + 'width' + 'padding-right' + 'border-right-width' + 'margin-right' = width of containing block`

You can also read that:

> If 'width' is set to 'auto', any other 'auto' values become '0' and 'width' follows from the resulting equality.

So the padding and border we be 0 and we will have:

`'margin-left' +  'width' + 'margin-right' = width of containing block`

then

`'width' = width of containing block - 'margin-left' - 'margin-right'`

It's clear now that if the margin are negative the width of the element will increase past the width of the containing block.

Comment: why in this example it doesn't increase the width ?
    <div class="div">thsi si bla bla</div>
    .div{
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        padding: 0 15px;
        margin-left: -15px;
        margin-right: -15px;
        background: pink;
        margin: 50px auto;
    }

Comment: @MouààdKd because you have set the value of width and it's no more auto